# Swift combine TimerPublisher without any subscribers

Tags: swift, combine

I have a question about [TimerPublisher](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/timerpublisher) in Apple's Combine framework. The docs say: *A publisher that repeatedly emits the current date on a given interval*. With non-Combine `Timer` objects, you can cancel them. How do you clean up after creating a `TimerPublisher` and connecting to it? Suppose I cancel all sinks and there is nothing subscribing to the timer publisher. Does the publisher still create some overhead in the system? If so, then how do I *cancel* the timer publisher?

Comment: When a subscriber cancels, it cancels the entire pipeline, including the `TimerPublisher`. So, `let c = Timer(...).autoconnect().sink {...}`, then `c.cancel()` would work. Or if, `c` simply de-inits

Comment: What would happen if you had multiple sinks? Eg `let c = Timer(...).autoconnect(); let s = c.sink {...}; let t = c.sink {...}`, then do you have to cancel *all* sinks to cancel the timer?

Comment: I guess not. I tried it in the terminal and New Dev is right, cancelling one sink cancels the timer publisher entirely, even if more sinks are connected. Not sure why this was down voted ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/triggering-events-repeatedly-using-a-timer). It's not obvious though. Here it is.

```
// create the timer and make it auto-connected
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

// cancel it upstream
self.timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
```